# Narrow Eclipse Refresh using native hooks or polling scope to specific project

Tags: eclipse, refresh, workspace

While checking the 
  **Refresh using native hooks or polling**

- (from Window->Preferences->General-Workspace)

Eclipse is searching for changes on files on the whole workspace (all the projects under the workspace).

Is there a way to narrow the scope to only one project from the workspace?
I'm editing the .css/.js/.html files using SublimeText (3rd party application), and want to see the changes on my server that Eclipse managed, but I have 10 projects under the workspace and Eclipse keep searching for updates on them also.

Comment: Yes, but you have to install a plugin. I wrote a simple example. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36555312/1509597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the automatic refresh is always for the entire workspace.

You can manually refresh a single project using 'File > Refresh' with the project selected.